# Why is ElasticSearch request failing after 10.000 documents?

Tags: nest, elk, elasticsearch.net

We are using ElasticSearch.NET / NEST to query an ElasticSearch configuration. The plan is to fetch in batches of 1000 documents and process them before fetching the next 1000 documents

However it always fails after processing 10 batches

```
ELK Search failed Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful (500)
```

If we change the batch-size to 10,000 it will fail after 1 batch
With batch size of 100 it will fail after 100 batches
Failure is always efter 10.000 documents

The code looks something like this

```
        private void ProcessRequest(SearchRequest request)
    {
        request.Size = 1000;
        for (request.From = 0; request.From < 1_000_000; request.From += request.Size)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(request.From);
            var responses = _client.Search<GroupStaticElkDocument>(request);
            foreach (var response in responses)
                _requestCounter.Add(response.ToRequest());
        }
    }
```

Comment: See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you shuld try paging/scrolling

Comment: I thought I was paging using the From property. Appearantly not. Yes scrolling does the trick